# exception when finishing a custom "new file wizard" in a RCP project

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, wizard

I am working with a custom "new file wizard". when i press the finish button i am expecting the eclipse to add a new file and show it correctly, but instead an exception occurs and i can't open the created file. But if i use this wizard for a second time, the exception doesn't occur and the file opens correctly. why?

the exception occurs when this line `getContainer().run(true, false, op)` executes.

and it is a part of the exception:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2012-07-28 16:15:01.239
!MESSAGE Unable to create class 'org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor' from bundle '33'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't find IDfind.ext
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:857)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:837)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:889)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:623)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:696)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:690)
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 3):

So the problem is that one of plugins that you have in your app requires a marker named find.ext. The error log shows IDfind.ext because the error message is concatenated without a space.

The happens if you have a custom application. Solution is quite easy:
Locate your WindowActionBarAdvisor that extends ActionBarAdvisor and defines your application initial menus and toolbars like File, Help, etc. etc.

Add this line:
    menu.add(new GroupMarker(IWorkbenchActionConstants.FIND_EXT));
f.e. to the method 
    createEditMenu.
or to any other menu entry.